# Implementing mutex/barrier in android Volley

Tags: java, android, mutex, barrier, cyclicbarrier

I have 20-30 cars in my recycleview.I have to load their current price from API.And every 20 minutes their prices are changing.To keep up-to-date prices I have volley requests for every each of them.

Problem is how to call `adapter.changeDataSetNotify()` method after all responses are done.

Comment: Please post code also.

Comment: I will prefer data bindings.

Comment: @RohitParmar what is that can u share link?